# Can I automatically merge duplicate objects in YAML files?

Tags: eclipse, merge, yaml, duplicates, array-merge

I am looking for a tool that automatically fixes up `YAML` lists. In reality, the latest entry is used when there is a duplicate. But I would like to merge duplicates.

For example, imagine a list like this (but huge)

```
members
    bob:
        certificates:
            - silver
    hank:
        certificates:
            - platinum
    hank:
        certificates:
            - gold
    joe:
        certificates:
            - platinum
```

I would like to find and merge duplicate keys. E.g.:

```
members
    bob:
        certificates:
            - silver
    hank:
        certificates:
            - platinum
            - gold
    joe:
        certificates:
            - platinum
```

I'm using the **YEdit Yaml Editor** in *Eclipse* and it would be nice to do this in there. Otherwise, I am using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't provide exactly the feature you want, using https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-wild-web-developer-web-development-eclipse-ide instead of YEdit will mark duplicate entries as errors on the file and in the Problems view. This will allow you to more easily spot them and remediate it manually (but you can then ask for enhancement to the project).